# Updating a particular cell of a gridview is not working , the update is not occured and there are some issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Good evening,someone asked me to help her with fixing some code for    asp.net, she showed me her code but I couldn't find a way to fix it .So I'm wondering if someone would take his time to help me fixing it.

As she said , she's using asp.net ( net f.4 ) .On a page she added a gridview and used a sqldatasource to bind the information from data table to the gridview .

- The aim is , on the GridView row_updating if the condition is true
  then a certain cell of the current editing row will be updated with a
  new value.
  But , here is the problem :
- Let's say I have two rows on the gridview!
- If I click the edit button of the first row and then press the update button nothing happens.
- But when I click the edit button of the second row then I can see the
  updated value for the cell updated of the first row and If I click update or cancel I
  can't see the value anymore.
- And in the datatable the value is not updated.

Can someone help me fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are not updating your gridview after executing Update statement. You need to   call DataBind() after update on gridview

```
GridView1.DataSource = yourDataSource;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi,I've tried and I get : The multi-part identifier "System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow" could not be bound. ( here com.ExecuteNonQuery(); )

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the `ID` to the `DataKeyNames` property, and then you can get the value like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" ...>
```

And in code-behind, you can get the ID like this:

```
var ID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["ID"];
```

Comment: Ok good but I have a problem when I press the update button I get error : Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.(  GridView1.DataBind(); ) . and when I refresh the page again the code worked ..but I always get the error , what can I do?

Comment: That's because you can't use a declarative datasource (`SqlDataSource`, `ObjectDataSource`, etc.) and assign the datasource in code-behind. Pick one or the other and you should be all set.